# Visual studio Code installation failed in OSX El Capitan

Tags: macos, visual-studio-code

So I have been trying to install visual studio code on my mac which is running on OS X El Capitan which got released not too long ago. Anyone else came across similar problem? Any work around?

Steps I took to download VS Code

1. Download Visual Studio Code for Mac from https://code.visualstudio.com/Download
2. Open the download and extracted the files into a new folder inside my Docouments
3. Dragged Visual Studio Code from folder to Applications
4. Prompted with a message if I want to install non-apple app, I clicked Yes.
5. Another window this time saying it might not be compatible with the OSX my mac is running on as shown below.

[image: Error message]

Comment: The only work around I can think of right now is using [Virtual box](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads) and running an earlier version of OS X, but at that point you could just run something like windows 7 and have the real visual studio.

Comment: @TimFreese VS Code is not a competitor to what you call "real" Visual Studio. It's essentially just a text editor.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Surprisingly, I have re-downloaded it again after a week and it has installed successfully. It seems like they Microsoft has fixed problem with El Capitan. I didn't do anything different so I really don't have a clue what the right solution is apart from re-downloading again which seem to have worked.

Answer (score 5):

From the [official website](https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/supporting/requirements):

> Visual Studio Code has been tested on the following platforms.
>
> - Ubuntu Desktop 14.04
> - OS X Yosemite
> - Windows 8.0, 8.1 and 10 (x86 and x64)

So it seems that El Capitan is yet to be fully tested or supported. It may work if you press "Ignore" on the warning message. It's also worth mentioning that VS Code is still a beta product.

Additionally version `v0.10.1` has been released, this will hopefully fix many issues, possibly even yours.

Answer (score 3):

The problem you were experiencing was as @DavidG said just because they had not tested it yet on el Capitan. The reason it now works is because it has been tested. But it would have worked anyway if you had just pressed the "Ignore button".